# How to test if a .txt file is already open by anyone?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to test if a .txt or .ini file is open already by anyone. I have several versions of IsFileOpen. Here is one taken directly from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ISFILEOPEN.ASPX

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Function isfileopen_test(FileName As String, _
    Optional ResultOnBadFile As Variant) As Variant
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' IsFileOpen_test
' This function determines whether a the file named by FileName is
' open by another process. The fuction returns True if the file is open
' or False if the file is not open. If the file named by FileName does
' not exist or if FileName is not a valid file name, the result returned
' if equal to the value of ResultOnBadFile if that parameter is provided.xd
' If ResultOnBadFile is not passed in, and FileName does not exist or
' is an invalid file name, the result is False.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim ErrNum As Integer
Dim V As Variant

On Error Resume Next

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' If we were passed in an empty string,
' there is no file to test so return FALSE.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If VBA.Trim(FileName) = vbNullString Then
    If IsMissing(ResultOnBadFile) = True Then
        isfileopen_test = False
    Else
        isfileopen_test = ResultOnBadFile
    End If
    Exit Function
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' if the file doesn't exist, it isn't open
' so get out now
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
V = Dir(FileName, vbNormal)
If IsError(V) = True Then
    ' syntactically bad file name
    If IsMissing(ResultOnBadFile) = True Then
        isfileopen_test = False
    Else
        isfileopen_test = ResultOnBadFile
    End If
    Exit Function
ElseIf V = vbNullString Then
    ' file doesn't exist.
    If IsMissing(ResultOnBadFile) = True Then
        isfileopen_test = False
    Else
        isfileopen_test = ResultOnBadFile
    End If
    Exit Function
End If

FileNum = FreeFile()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Err.Clear
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #FileNum
ErrNum = Err.Number
''''''''''''''''''''
' Close the file.
''''''''''''''''''''
Close FileNum
On Error GoTo 0

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Check to see which error occurred.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Select Case ErrNum
    Case 0
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        isfileopen_test = False
    Case 70
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        isfileopen_test = True
    Case Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Another error occurred. Assume open.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        isfileopen_test = True
End Select

End Function
```

I need to do this via VBA. I can't get it to work for a .txt or .ini file. How can I check if a txt or ini file is already open by someone on the network?

Edit: It returns false for txt and ini files whether they are open or not.

If you are so inclined, I am attempting to build a distributive computing system on a clients network. I've never done this before and I am looking to keep it as simple as possible, so I was thinking of communicating via txt files. MSMQ looks good, but it looks like a long learning curve. I've already read all of the posts on stackoverflow regarding distributive computing.

Comment: What isn't working with that example? How are you testing it?

Comment: Please expand on 'not working'. If a user of your distributed computing system told you it was 'not working', how would you fix it? Do you get an error or unexpected result? For starters that function has has `On Error Resume Next` at the top which is bad news. That function sure has a lot of complicated code around 'result on bad file'

Comment: @Comintern I added an edit.

Comment: Are you sure the process that has the file "open" is locking it? Most text utilities don't lock files unless they are actively writing to them.  That said, have you considered memory mapped files?

Comment: @Comintern To your first question: probably not. I'll have to look into how to test it. To your second question: No, please share if you can. I'll try to google it.

Comment: From the question, it sounds like you're looking for a form of inter-process communication.  Memory mapped files can be used similarly to shared memory.  There's some (really old and incomplete) code I posted on a forum back in the day [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?404085-VB6-Treat-a-file-like-an-array-without-reading-to-memory).

Comment: @Comintern I looked into the memory mapping file stuff and it looks very interesting. Sadly, I don't have time. I decided to split the processing up via sorting the file names that have to be processed alphabetically on all the PCs and have them process the 1st x%, the 2nd y%, etc. depending on how many files there are. If someone wants to post something on memory mapping files via VBA Lars post will be a good start: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/93240.aspx

Comment: @Comintern If you are able to chime in on this related post that would be great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218821/how-to-store-data-in-and-get-data-out-of-memory-mapping-files-using-copymemory-i  I tried my solution above and it worked great, but it is not dynamic enough for me. Going back to memory mapping files (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to try to rename the file with the same name:

```
Public Function IsFileLocked(file_path As String) As Boolean
  Dim num As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  Name file_path As file_path
  num = Err.Number
  On Error GoTo 0

  If num <> 0 And num <> 75 Then Error num
  IsFileLocked = num <> 0
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The *OpenFiles* command uses `NetFileEnum`

> The NetFileEnum function returns information about some or all open files on a server, depending on the parameters specified.

```
NET_API_STATUS NetFileEnum(
  LMSTR servername,
  LMSTR basepath,
  LMSTR username,
  DWORD level,
  LPBYTE* bufptr,
  DWORD prefmaxlen,
  LPDWORD entriesread,
  LPDWORD totalentries,
  PDWORD_PTR resume_handle
);
```

It says it also does local computer but *Openfiles* requires a flag to be set for local files. Run *GFlags* and tick *Maintain a list of objects for each type*.

Note Notepad opens, reads, and closes the file. Therefore Notepad holds no file open.

For a local computer you can call `enumwindows`, and see if your filename is in any of the Window's Captions. This sample uses `GetWindow` but the docs say `EnumWindows` is preferred.

```
Public Declare Function GetTopWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
       Private Const GW_CHILD = 5
       Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    Sub WindowList()
        Dim hwnd As Long
            hwnd = GetTopWindow(0)
            If hwnd <> 0 Then
                AddChildWindows hwnd, 0
            End If
    End Sub

    Private Function AddChildWindows(ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal Level As Long) As String
        Dim gwfnhwnd As Long, X As Long, WT As String, CN As String, Length As Long, hwnd As Long, TID As Long, PID As Long, MN As String, Ret As Long, Parenthwnd As Long
        Static Order As Long
        Static FirstTime As Long
        Parenthwnd = hwndParent
        If Level = 0 Then
                        hwnd = hwndParent
        Else
            hwnd = GetWindow(hwndParent, GW_CHILD)
        End If
        Do While hwnd <> 0
                  WT = Space(512)
                  Length = GetWindowText(hwnd, WT, 508)
                  WT = Left$(WT, Length)
                  If WT = "" Then WT = Chr(171) & "No Window Text " & Err.LastDllError & Chr(187)
                  CN = Space(512)
                  Length = GetClassName(hwnd, CN, 508)
                  CN = Left$(CN, Length)
                  If CN = "" Then CN = "Error=" & Err.LastDllError
                  MsgBox WT & " " & CN
                  hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
    End Function
```

COM can communicate across computers and processes. Just use Class modules to build interfaces betweeen processes.

Comment: Not sure it makes a difference to the OP, but: ["Only members of the Administrators or Server Operators local group can successfully execute the NetFileEnum function."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)